# didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: django-views

This is the error I am getting

```
The view djangocricket.Cricket.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

here is my views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

it is exactly as the tutorial says. :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

You forget `return` python reserved word.